# How to show all days recorded

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in Sql Server named `Lab_Analysis(ID int,Date Date,HeatNo decimal(18,3),Mn decimal(18,3),CaO decimal(18,3))`

Now if i want to View Sum of HeatNo, Mn, CaO then i will have to enter Month and Year. Suppose i give month = 2(means February) then it should show sum of HeatNo, Mn, CaO of each days of that Month and if on any days there is no Record found then it should 0. For this I did following:

```
Declare @D table(Dt int,Val decimal(18,3))
insert into @D values(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,0), 
(10,0),(11,0),(12,0),(13,0),(14,0),(15,0),(16,0),(17,0),(18,0),(19,0), 
(20,0),(21,0),(22,0),(23,0),(24,0),(25,0),(26,0),(27,0),(28,0),(29,0),(30,0),(31,0)

SELECT D.Dt,ISNULL(SUM(L.HeatNo),0) HeatNo FROM @D D LEFT JOIN Lab_Analysis 
L ON DATEPART(dd,L.Date)=D.Dt where DATEPART(MM,L.Date)=2 GROUP BY D.Dt
```

Here in the February month Records are inserted only on 11 and 13 February. The above query is showing only rows but it shows all days records. if no record found on any days then it should show 0 which is not showing by the above query. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the L.Date in your where clause DATEPART(MM,L.Date)=2, that converts your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN, you need to add this condition in the ON clause

```
Declare @D table(Dt int,Val decimal(18,3))
insert into @D values(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,0), 
(10,0),(11,0),(12,0),(13,0),(14,0),(15,0),(16,0),(17,0),(18,0),(19,0), 
(20,0),(21,0),(22,0),(23,0),(24,0),(25,0),(26,0),(27,0),(28,0),(29,0),(30,0),(31,0)

SELECT D.Dt,ISNULL(SUM(L.HeatNo),0) HeatNo 
FROM @D D 
LEFT JOIN Lab_Analysis L ON 
    DATEPART(dd,L.Date)=D.Dt 
    AND DATEPART(MM,L.Date)=2 
GROUP BY D.Dt
```

Instead of create that set of values for each month, I recomend you to use a CTE to create your dates

```
DECLARE 
    @Year INT, 
    @Month INT, 
    @start DATE, 
    @end DATE

SET @Year = 2019
SET @Month = 2
SET @start = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1)
SET @end = DATEADD(day, -1,DATEADD(month, 1, @start))

;WITH dates AS (
    SELECT @start as theDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @end
)
SELECT D.theDate,ISNULL(SUM(L.HeatNo),0) HeatNo 
FROM dates D
LEFT JOIN Lab_Analysis L ON L.Date = theDate
GROUP BY theDate
```

Comment: It Works fine for me. Thanks.